# Google Drive Sharing Folders

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to share a folder from a Ruby script using the following code:

```
def insert_file_permission(file_id, email)
  drive = $client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
  new_permission = drive.permissions.insert.request_schema.new({
    'value' => email,
    'type' => 'user',
    'role' => 'reader'
  })
  result = $client.execute(
    :api_method => drive.permissions.insert,
    :body_object => new_permission,
    :parameters => { 'fileId' => file_id, 'emailMessage' => 'This a shared folder', 'sendNotificationEmails' => true, 'withLink' => false})
  log_results(email +': ' + file_id +' - file permission',result, true)
end
```

The share details when I look at the folder from the Owner's login show the folder as being shared by those users.  But when I log in as the user account specified by the parameter "email", the folder is not visible in the their Drive.

I added the email options to see if this was related to a bug/feature that required users to click a link in an email to activate the share, but that seems to make it worse.  They then get a message that they need to request access, which is odd since they are already listed as Shares.

Comment: UPDATE:  This may have something to do with Google Apps taking a very long time to register deleted users, and having deleted users "percolate" through the system.  I've been using a small set of users and folders for testing, and deleting those users as part of the exhaustive tests, which may have caused Google Apps to get confused.

Comment: UPDATE: Well that appears to be the problem. Cycling through my test set of users was causing Google Apps to get its knickers in a twist. It all seems to work as expected with fresh user data, or ample time between test cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patience is a virtue.  The answer is to give Google Apps for Business time to "catch up" when creating and deleting user accounts, especially when testing permissions on Google Drive.